# How to set an invisible occluder in OpenGL 2

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rendering, render

I have two objects on a 3D scene (rendered with [glDrawElements](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml)). When one of them passes behind the other, it is occluded and not visible anymore (the normal behaviour anyone would expect).

What I want to do next, is to **make invisible the foreground object** (I want the background object (blue) to disappear when it goes behind the foreground object (dashed) and re-appear when it comes back to the other side, keeping the foreground object un-rendered).

[image]

*Only render the blue parts!*

I'm using OpenGL 2, though I'm pretty new on it.

Comment: You mean that you want the foregorund object to still occlude the background object, but in practice you see through both? What have you tried?

Comment: The "foreground" object is static and should never be drawn (Something else will be put there later on!). The background object moves around the first one, when it passes behind, it should be "occluded" (disappear) just as it would normally do.

Comment: What have you tried to do and what happens with your code in your current state?

Comment: Now I draw both objects normally (both visible). I tried adding an alpha value to the color of the foreground but didn't work (you can still see the background object when it's behind). Tried flipping the normals of the foreground so they become non-visible (don't seem to work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use the glColorMask which can enable/disable writes to the color buffer.(https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml)

In pseudo-code this would be:

```
glClear(...);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);// disable writes to color buffer
renderForegroundObject();
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE); // enable writes to color buffer
renderBlueObject();
swapBuffers();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can draw your foreground object only in the Z-buffer, just disable color writes and leave Z-buffer write enabled. This will fill-up some screen area with new Z values, without changing any color.

Then, when you draw your background object in a standard way it will hide behind the new Z-values, so you should get what you want.

BTW: You can do the same with stencil buffer but I think that using just Z-buffer is  simpler.